# Apache Airflow: Gunicorn Configuration File Not Being Read?

Tags: python, virtualenv, config, gunicorn, airflow

I'm trying to run Apache Airflow's webserver from a virtualenv on a Redhat machine, with some configuration options from a Gunicorn config file. Gunicorn and Airflow are both installed in the virtualenv. The command `airflow webserver` starts Airflow's webserver and the Gunicorn server. The config file has options to make sure Gunicorn uses/accepts TLSv1.2 only, as well as a list of ciphers to use.

The Gunicorn config file is `gunicorn.py`. This file is referenced through an environment variable `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--config=/path/to/gunicorn.py ..."` in `.bashrc`. This variable also sets a couple of other variables in addition to `--config`. However, when I run the `airflow webserver` command, the options in `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS` are never applied.

Seeing as how Gunicorn is not called from command line, but instead by Airflow, I'm assuming this is why the `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS` environment variable is not read, but I'm not sure and I'm new to both technologies...

TL;DR:
Is there another way to set up Gunicorn to automatically reference a config file, without the `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS` environment variable?

Here's what I'm using:

- gunicorn 19.8.1
- apache-airflow 1.9.0
- python 2.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Gunicorn is called by Airflow, it uses `~\airflow\www\gunicorn_config.py` as its config file.